# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3982/community-promotion-ads-2013)

Apparently there's never been one of these on Server Fault. Let's amend that, shall we? ♪

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Users of the community will provide images and content links, and then community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool server utilities
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/ads/display/2468).

Comment: For reference, this is what other sites do [SuperUser](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3957/community-promotion-ads-2012), [Apple](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/455/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011), and [Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2158/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012)

Comment: Can we use the inline URL format, rather than the annoyingly unreadable reference style?

Answer (score 26):

[image: Try OpenIndiana Today]

Comment: Perhaps a bit blasé?

Comment: Yep, but Oracle deserves it.

Comment: Can't say it really hits the mark for me, as none of the listed features are unique selling points... all of them are also found in Oracle's own "grown up" successor to  OpenSolaris, namely Solaris 11.

Comment: @scottishwildcat Yes, but most of the core developers of those features left Sun before, during or after the Oracle acquisition. It could be cogently argued that, while the names are the same, the products are of a much higher quality in OpenIndiana that is the benefactor of the engineers who no longer work at Sun/Oracle. Solaris's DTrace isn't the same as OpenIndiana's DTrace.

Comment: DTrace is a perfect example where the open source version is superior to Suns's, and almost certainly will be so long as Bryan M. Cantrill is running Joyent, and Oracle keeps Solaris closed.

Comment: @ChrisS I don't disagree, was just saying there's nothing in the proposed ad to indicate that's the case. It's just a list of features that, on the face of it, could just as well be a Solaris 11 feature list, which in itself doesn't give me any compelling reason to click. (And of course, as long as Bryan Cantrill keeps DTrace open, presumably Oracle are quite entitled to include Joyent's version in Solaris if they so wish…)

Comment: @scottishwildcat Nope, the CDDL does not allow you to use the covered software if you impose new restrictions on it. Proprietary and infectious licenses like the GPL need not apply. Same reason the BSDs and OpenSolaris derivatives get along, they can freely use each others code.

Comment: Your move Oracle. Your move.

Comment: @WesleyDavid - bit of a problem with the image from where I'm sitting at least, imgur isn't displaying it at all.

Comment: @RobMoir Fixed. I thought when I uploaded the image to imgur, which gave the image its own URL, I could remove it from my own hosting account. I'm so confused...

Comment: Alls well that ends well, or something

Answer (score 21):

[image: Choose your way with FreeBSD]

Comment: CP/M -- Because nobody wants to hack THAT!

Comment: @voretaq7 So I've converted you to my side?

Comment: @ChrisS Secure: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DpB75.png Creation: http://i.imgur.com/gz1Si.png Choice: http://i.imgur.com/FR25D.png

Answer (score 21):

[image: Credit Card Sized Computer]

Comment: I like - ordering one myself - but this is a bit "your point being...?" without some text.

Comment: maybe something along "Computing credit card sized" ?

Comment: Sure, that works

Comment: nice changes. Definitely works for me.

Answer (score 18):

[image: lighttpd: fly light]

Comment: Because poor lighty could use some love between all these Apache and nginx questions!

Comment: I'm wondering which conclusion to jump to - It's unpopular or it's so easy to use that people don't need to ask questions about it. Maybe I should try it out for myself.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers Give it a shot; it's unpopular, at least relative to the major players, but that's not a good indicator of its quality (or ease of use).

Answer (score 17):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Open Source Host-based Intrusion Detection System]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Network management and monitoring]

Comment: It should have a tag line or something so that people would know what is this project about. Maybe *"network management and monitoring"* as mentioned currently on the website.

Answer (score 0):

[image: netsniff-ng - the packet sniffing beast]

Answer (score -11):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: The algorithm that SF uses to tweet Posts needs some tweaking before I could support this... It's generally the worst Questions that get tweeted, not really some I'd prefer to advertise.

Comment: @Chris: feel free to down-vote... ;-) The point of these ads is that they're *community-chosen*. I'm sure you can think of things more worthy to advertise, and propose them here...

Comment: You mean that twitter feed isn't supposed to be "vote to close" suggestions? I'm staggered. We'd love to promote a twitter feed that was actually worthwhile.

Comment: I have yet to see *any* feed on Twitter I'd consider "worthwhile", @Rob - but last I checked, they let just about anyone create new ones, so you could certainly have a go at creating your own "best-of" feed there... Heck, you could even promote it with an ad here I suppose.

Comment: You have obviously not been exposed to the greatness of @Nonapeptide.

Comment: @RobMoir: Take a look at this: http://quickmediasolutions.com/stackbot