# Sidebar ad displays an error message from imgur.com

Tags: support, advertising

Just refreshed the Server Fault main page and saw this in the right sidebar:

[image]

The image location emdedded into the page is [http://i.imgur.com/LZEzv.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/LZEzv.jpg) the alt text is `Try OpenIndiana Today`

Comment: As a temp fix, I mangled the [relevant answer](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3063/3) creating this in the community ad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because imgur.com returns an http status code of 200 for that image, there's really no way for us to detect when an image is no longer available.

[SvenW's](https://meta.serverfault.com/users/8897/svenw) action to edit the [offending community ad](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/3063/3) was the proper one until its author can upload a new image.

Comment: You *could* test if the md5 of the data returned is `eebc93350a68a64022b7482f460017ba` (known to be the "image not found" image) once day or so, and auto 'exclude' bad ads. That would be quite a bit of work for something that's rarely a problem, easily spotted, and easily dealt with manually.

Comment: We're going to require that images are hosted on our i.stack.imgur subdomain, so hopefully they won't randomly disappear.

Comment: I strongly suspect this one was the result of DMCA or similar; not the owner deleting it.