# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool server utilities
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](http://meta.serverfault.com/ads/display/3982).

Comment: [Last year's ads in case anyone wants to resurrect one](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2468/community-promotion-ads-2012)

Comment: Can it be a commercial company advertisement?

Comment: @ibrahim I don't believe there's a specific ban on advertising commercial products, but if someone wants to place a commercial ad they should [talk to Stack Exchange (ads@stackexchange.com or the phone number)](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact) - I'm told the ad rates are pretty reasonable, and I know these sites can't be cheap to run :)

Answer (score 47):

[image: The quieter you become, the more you are able to hear...]

Comment: What does REDFINED mean?

Comment: Months. MONTHS! And nobody tells me....

Answer (score 40):

[image: FreeBSD - more than Creation]

Comment: The Rotation - Secure: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DpB75.png Creation: http://i.imgur.com/gz1Si.png Choice: http://i.imgur.com/FR25D.png

Answer (score 30):

[image: How to build, design and test the security of web applications and web services.]

Answer (score 28):

[image: Open Source Host-based Intrusion Detection System]

Answer (score 27):

[image: If your data is important to you, back it up!]

Comment: If anyone wants to work on this image feel free - Gimp is being its usually gimp-y self (I wanted a black background, but apparently I NO CAN HAS without artifacts)

Comment: It was a lot quality JPEG, wasn't it?

Comment: @ChrisS Yup. Both images. Were the bat's wings your first clue?

Comment: When I did a Color->Map->Color Exchange White to Black and dialed up the threashold, instead of neatly blending the colors I get aliased artifacts galore. Classic symptom of crappy JPEGs.

Comment: Shouldn't it say OS X instead of Mac?

Comment: @MDMarra Probably, but I used their official tagline from http://bacula.org

Answer (score 21):

[image: lighttpd: fly light]

Answer (score 21):

[image: Prioritize. Save time. Stay focused.]

Answer (score 21):

[image: Enterprise-class Linux]

Answer (score 16):

[image: Barman - Backup and Recovery Manager for PostgreSQL]

Comment: You may want to add this to [dba.se]'s community promotion ads too - there's a decent Postgres contingent over there.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Debian -- The Universal Operating System]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Configuration Management made easy]

Comment: This was my introduction to Rudder. Glad I now know about it. Good, simple Ad.

Comment: I'm glad that it helps

Answer (score -6):

[image: Let us serve your Bootstrap]

Comment: The ad should give a sense of what the product does. I can't tell, at a glance, what BootstrapCDN does. See the Barman ad as an example... it's very clear that Barman is a backup manager for PostgresSQL.

Comment: A CDN ad seems more appropriate for [webmasters.SE] than Server Fault IMHO. I dropped it [on their community ads question](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/911/14055)

Answer (score -9):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. Last cycle, y'all knocked it deep into the sea with downvotes.

Comment: we have to have a "discussion" with the twitter question-selection algorithm at some point -- [has it gotten any better at posting good questions](https://twitter.com/serverfault)?

Comment: @voretaq7 No, I don't think it's gotten any better.